# 3 cheque accounts 2 constructors for cust without overdraft but cust who does not want overdraft is getting one

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, superclass

ChequeAccount class extends Account class. Account class holds ID, name and balance attributes. ChequesAccount class has overdraftLimit, amtOverdrawn and transactionNo plus super(ID, name, balance) from Account. I have created 3 chqAccount objects in an array and printed their details. Ringo has opted out of overdraft facility in his chq account so separate constructor for him. However when i print the details for all cheque accounts he is the only one who gets the overdraft facility. Its doing my head in, please help

```
public class TestAccounts6
{
   private static ChequeAccount[] chqAccount = new ChequeAccount[5];
   private static int indexNo = 0;

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      ChequeAccount c1 = new ChequeAccount("S1111", "Paul", 1245.00, 0, 0, 0);
      ChequeAccount c2 = new ChequeAccount("S2222", "Ringo", 2500.00);
      ChequeAccount c3 = new ChequeAccount("S3333", "John", 1575.00, 0, 0, 0);
      chqAccount[0] = c1;
      chqAccount[1] = c2;
      chqAccount[2] = c3;
      indexNo = 3;
      System.out.printf("%-10s%-10s%-10s%-10s%-10s%-10s%n", "ID", "Name", "Balance",
                        "Overdraft", "Amount", "No of");
      System.out.printf("%-10s%-10s%-10s%-10s%-10s%-10s%n", "", "", "",
                        "Limit", "Overdrawn", "Transactions\n");
      for (int i = 0; i < indexNo; i++)
      {
         chqAccount[i].print();
      }

   }

}
public class ChequeAccount extends Account
{
   protected double overdraftLimit = 10000;
   protected double amtOverdrawn = 0;
   protected int transactionNo = 0;

   // constructor
   public ChequeAccount(String ID, String name, double balance,
                        double overdraftLimit, double amtOverdrawn,
                        int transactionNo)
   {
      super(ID, name, balance);
      this.overdraftLimit = overdraftLimit;
      this.amtOverdrawn = amtOverdrawn;
      this.transactionNo = transactionNo;
   }

   public ChequeAccount(String ID, String name, double balance)
   {
      super(ID, name, balance);
   }

   public void print()
   {

      System.out.printf("%-10s%-10s$%-9.2f$%-9.2f$%-9.2f%-10d%n", ID, name,
                        balance, overdraftLimit, amtOverdrawn, transactionNo);
   }

}
public class Account
{
   protected String ID;
   protected String name;
   protected double balance;

   // Constructor
   public Account(String ID, String name, double balance)
   {
      this.ID = ID;
      this.name = name;
      this.balance = balance;
   }
```

Expected ringo would not get overdraft facility and John and Paul would. Opposite to expectations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is behaving correctly. Because

1. you have created 3 chqAccount objects

> ChequeAccount c1 = new ChequeAccount("S1111", "Paul", 1245.00, 0, 0,
>   0);
>
> ChequeAccount c2 = new ChequeAccount("S2222", "Ringo", 2500.00);
>
> ChequeAccount c3 = new ChequeAccount("S3333", "John", 1575.00, 0, 0,
>   0);

2. when you try to print the values of this objects.
   it is printing the following way.

> ID        Name      Balance   Overdraft Amount    No of
>                                 Limit     Overdrawn Transactions
>
> S1111     Paul      $1245.00  $0.00     $0.00     0          S2222
>   Ringo     $2500.00  $10000.00 $0.00     0          S3333     John
>   $1575.00  $0.00     $0.00     0

when we observe the above  and check the Ringo's details. it has Balance as : $10000.00 because you have not assigned any values to Ringo . But in  ChequeAccount  as following.

```
  protected double overdraftLimit = 10000;
  protected double amtOverdrawn = 0;
  protected int transactionNo = 0;
```

it has default value . so that while printing it is taking default values.

Comment: Thanks Raju, so i would set the overdraftlimit using a assessor for individual customers

Answer (score 0):

That is the expected behaviour of the code.

```
public class ChequeAccount extends Account
{
   protected double overdraftLimit = 10000;
   protected double amtOverdrawn = 0;
   protected int transactionNo = 0;
   ...
}
```

You have assigned default values for these variables. When you call the constructor for **Ringo** then these variables are not updated, as a result, the default values you have assigned will be used.

With **Paul** and **John** you are assigning new values (all 0's) to these variables so they will be printed out instead.

```
ChequeAccount c1 = new ChequeAccount("S1111", "Paul", 1245.00, 10000, 0, 0);
ChequeAccount c2 = new ChequeAccount("S2222", "Ringo", 2500.00);
ChequeAccount c3 = new ChequeAccount("S3333", "John", 1575.00, 10000, 0, 0);
```

```
public class ChequeAccount extends Account
{
   protected double overdraftLimit = 0;
   protected double amtOverdrawn = 0;
   protected int transactionNo = 0;
   ...
}
```

Modifying your code with the above changes will now display an overdraft limit of more than zero for **Paul** and **John** while making **Ringo's** limit 0.